# Apply Changes to Prefab - Unity 2018

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have whole gameplay prefab that I was using for instantiating game multiple time.
Gameplay prefab contains other child prefabs within it. Before Unity 2018, we have direct Apply button to write all changes about prefab modification within the disk.

Now after Unity 2018 launch, Unity change few settings within Prefab structure, now we don't have direct Apply button to save changes.

Currently, I want to save the whole prefab together but I can't able to do this. I require to pick each item then click on Apply as Override button.

Please check below image:
[image]

If I directly press **Apply All** button then Unity gets crashed and Applying changes to an individual item is the most tedious task.

So please guide me into this so I can speed up my work.

Answer (score 1):

The "Apply All" should work fine. If the Unity is crashing when you click "Apply All" then open a bug with Unity Technologies.

As a workaround I suggest you to create a script to [Extend the Unity Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExtendingTheEditor.html) and create a button execute the action.
Have a look in the [PrefabUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.html) class documentation.

The [PrefabUtility.ApplyPrefabInstance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.ApplyPrefabInstance.html) should do the job for you.